# Update Entry with a StringVar variable when the file is updated. Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to update Entry with a StringVar variable when the file is updated

I tried with a while loop until the word FIN is read, but it does not work. How could it be done? Thank you

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk() 
var = StringVar(value="texto")

def archivo():
    global var
    salir = False
    f=open("test.txt","r")
    while not salir:
        linea = f.readline()
        var.set(linea)
        if "FIN" in linea:
            salir = True
archivo()
Label(root, text="Texto desde archivo").pack()
t = Entry(root, textvariable = var) 
t.pack() 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please give us the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem: there's probably no need to use tkinter here. Also, try to use variable names in English when posting on SO, it will make your code easier to understand for everyone!

Comment: I would like to do this one in tkinter, is a example